# How can one make a table without borders?

Tags: tables

How can I make a table without borders?

Thanks!

Comment: The default table doesn’t have any borders (see [the LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) for a good introduction to tables). What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I know the question is very, very basic. But please do not downvote just for that. (Or if you do please leave a reason for doing so)

Comment: I edited your question title to better reflect the question. Feel free to revert it if you wish.

Comment: It is worth your time to read the documentation for the booktabs package. It explains both the principles and practice behind making a good looking table.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A table without borders:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
first row & & \\
second row & & \\
and & so & on \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks, very concise! I've understood that "{ccc}" means "center center center", and so i did a better "{ r c l }"

Comment: "better" in this case is a matter of taste, I like {l l l } since it looks better...